# NullPointerException: null in Play Framework 2.3.1

Tags: playframework, nullpointerexception, migration, playframework-2.3

Actually im going to migrate play framework 2.0.8 in 2.3.1 and have adjusted the corresponding changes. This Error leave me in the shadow, when i run the code:

> NullPointerException: null
>   No source available, here is the exception stack trace:

java.lang.NullPointerException:

```
 akka.actor.IndirectActorProducer$.apply(Props.scala:305)

 akka.actor.Props.producer(Props.scala:173)

 akka.actor.Props.<init>(Props.scala:186)

 Global.onStart(Global.java:105)

 play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:22)

 play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:220)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)

 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)

 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)

 scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:105)

 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)

 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)

 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)

 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)

 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)

 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I began using play with the 2.2 version and switching to 2.3 lead to the following errors :

- not more play console command but rather activator.
- some change in the build configuration files (don't remember exactly what).

How did you proceed ? Here is what I'll do if I had to do what you are doing :

- activator new.
- copy/past all the app/ and public/ folders.
- rewriting all the building files (dependency and stuff) since they change since the last version.

Anyway it is hard to help you with how few information you gave us. Consider giving us your root play application tree and the build conf settings.

Answer (score 0):

My Proeceed:

1. I create a new app with the "activator new" command
2. copy/past the app (except configuration/setting files like build settings)
3. adjust configuration/setting files
4. adjust the code
5. connect Database

Thats is!